# SQL syntax error: MySQL server RETURNS timestamp deterministic BEGIN

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-function

I am getting the following error:

> 1064 - SQL syntax; MySQL server RETURNS timestamp deterministic BEGIN DECLARE
>   dt_act timestamp; sele' at line 1

This is my code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS NewProc;
DELIMITER //
CREATE  FUNCTION NewProc(f_test varchar)
 RETURNS timestamp deterministic
BEGIN


DECLARE dt_act timestamp;
    select cast((case
when str_to_date(activation_date,'%d-%M-%Y') is not null then date_format(str_to_date(activation_date,'%d-%M-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') 
when str_to_date(activation_date,'%d-%m-%Y') is not null then date_format(str_to_date(activation_date,'%d-%m-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
ELSE
date_format(str_to_date(activation_date,'%Y-%M-%d'),'%Y-%m-%d')
end) as timestamp ) into dt_act from abc where phone_no =f_test;

    RETURN dt_act;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

---

***ERROR:***

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>    near ')  RETURNS timestamp deterministic BEGIN DECLARE dt_act timestamp;     sele' at line 1

Comment: Where is the question?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "**A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same result for the same input parameters, and “not deterministic” otherwise**. If neither DETERMINISTIC nor NOT DETERMINISTIC is given in the routine definition, the default is NOT DETERMINISTIC. To declare that a function is deterministic, you must specify DETERMINISTIC explicitly" source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html. **With other words you are using `deterministic` wrong so you should remove it or change it into non deterministic**

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
 RETURNS timestamp deterministic
BEGIN


DECLARE dt_act timestamp;
 sele' at line 1
This is the error

Comment: You have not specified a size for your `VARCHAR` input, try changing it to `VARCHAR(50)` or something appropriate